# Adding a label to a ggplot line rather than point

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, label

I have a dataframe of species frequencies. I am graphing abundance over time and want to label the species that are most common. I have a dataframe with the following five columns - date, species, frequency, site, treatment. At present I am doing something along the lines of:

```
df %>%
  mutate(majorSpp = ifelse(frequency > 0.4, as.character(species), "")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = frequency, colour = species, group = species)) +
    geom_line() +
    facet_grid(type ~ treatment)
    geom_label_repel(aes(label=majorSpp))
```

However, this approach means that if a species has a frequency of > 0.4 on multiple dates, the line is labeled at each of the multiple points, rather than just once. What I need is to assign a species name to majorSpp only for the point where that species' frequency is highest over all the dates it was measured. But I can't quite figure out how to fit that logic into a mutate function.

I'm open to other labeling solutions such as directlabel if this is easy to achieve out of the box in some other package.

**EDIT:**

Example data:

```
df <- data.frame(date = c(01-02-2020, 01-02-2020, 04-04-2020, 04-04-2020), 
                 species = c("cat", "dog", "cat", "dog"), 
                 frequency = c(0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 0.5),
                 site = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'a'),
                 treatment = c(1, 1, 1, 1))
```

If I create a label for any frequency above 0.4, I get two labels generated for "dog". The reason I want to do this is that I have about 50 species, but most of them have a frequency of zero most of the time. So using something like colour and a legend is useless.

A partial solution:

```
df %>%
  mutate(majorSpp = ifelse(frequency > 0.4, as.character(species), "")) -> temp
temp$majorSpp[duplicated(temp$majorSpp)] <- NA
temp %>%
    ggplot ...
```

There are two problems with this, if you facet by additional columns, then each majorSpp is only shown once, over the entire plot, whereas ideally, it would be shown once in every facet where it had a frequency above 0.4. Secondly, and not very importantly, it breaks the nice pipe flow.

I have attached a picture of the plot I generate using this partial solution below:[image]

Comment: Provide some data please. Read the posting guide.

Comment: To clarify, you have a line plot, but you want only 1 label per line?  If so, you may need to rethink how you define the variable containing the label information so it only appears once, i.e. at one time point.  Maybe on only the first date, or last date? Consider adding this label explicitly as a new column to your `df` data frame before calling ggplot.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, @Earlien. Unfortunately, I didn't mention I was faceting the data and that would mean the label would then only appear once per plot, rather than once per facet (provided freq > 0.4).

Comment: To clarify, if a species has frequency > 0.4 at *any* given date, you want to have *one* label for that entire species to signify it had a frequency > 0.4 (NOT a label at each date that this occurs)? If so, how many of 50 species would likely satisfy this? I would still suggest using a legend, and either demark those lines by colour or linetype, which map to the same, single value of the legend, "Species with >0.4 freq" or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The secret sauce I was missing was "group_by". Note that summarise gets rid of grouping so you need to re-add it.

```
df %>%
  filter(morphology != "inanimate") %>%
  group_by(type, date, treatment, species) %>%
  summarise(av = mean(presence), morphology = unique(morphology)) %>%
  group_by(treatment, type) %>%
  mutate(majorSpp = ifelse(av > 0.6, as.character(species), "")) %>%
  mutate(majorSpp = ifelse(duplicated(majorSpp), '', majorSpp)) %>%
  ungroup(treatment, type) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = av, colour = morphology, group = species)) +
    geom_line() +
    facet_grid(treatment ~ type) +
    geom_label_repel(aes(label=majorSpp), size=2)
```

produced:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this could help, but if I understand are you looking for something like this? Let me know how this fits for your problem:

```
#Data
mdf <- structure(list(date = c(-2021, -2021, -2020, -2020, -2021, -2021, 
-2020, -2020), species = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L), .Label = c("cat", "dog"), class = "factor"), frequency = c(0.1, 
0.5, 0.6, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0), a_bunch_of_other_cols = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L), .Label = c("a", "x", "y", "z"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")

#Code
mdf %>%
  mutate(majorSpp = ifelse(frequency > 0.4, as.character(species), "")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = frequency, colour = species, group = species)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line()+
  geom_label_repel(aes(label=majorSpp),show.legend = F)+
  facet_wrap(~a_bunch_of_other_cols)
```

[image]